# What is the basis of the vector space of polynomials of any degree?

Tags: functional-analysis, polynomials, vector-spaces, dimensional-analysis

Could we say that the set $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4,\cdots\}$ is a basis of the vector space of polynomials ?

Note that, for example the set $\{e_1,e_2,e_3,\cdots\}$ such that $e_n=(\delta_{n,k})_{k \in \mathbb{N^*}} $ is not a basis for the vector space $\mathbb{R}^\infty$, even though the set $\{e_1,e_2,e_3,\cdots,e_n\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$.

Comment: You missed $x$ in your set. With $x$ added in, it is true that this set is a basis of the vector space of polynomials, because every polynomial is a **finite** linear combination of these.

Comment: also note that, while your observation about $\mathbb R^\infty$ is important and correct, $\sum_{k \in \mathbb N_0} x^k$ is not a polynomial so it doesn't have to be a linear combination by the vectors in your basis while $$\sum_{k \in \mathbb N_0} e_k \in \mathbb R^\infty$$holds.

Comment: @WhatsUp Thanks, i get it.

Comment: @Targon yes sure, i get it know, so every polynomial must end somewhere, so we can then make a combination.